# Optimize Javascript code

Tags: jquery

I have a map with a bunch of link images on top of it. They all have the same image, with different positions.

```
<div id="map" class="small-12 large-9 left">
 <img src="a-map.jpg">
  <a class="city1"><img class="large-12 small-8" src="fundita-mov.png"></a>
  <a class="city2"><img class="large-12 small-8" src="fundita-mov.png"></a>
  <a class="city3"><img class="large-12 small-8" src="fundita-mov.png"></a>
  <a class="city4"><img class="large-12 small-8" src="fundita-mov.png"></a>
  <a class="city5"><img class="large-12 small-8" src="fundita-mov.png"></a>
</div>
```

The css for them (you get the idea)

```
#map a{position:absolute;}
a.cityx{left: 35%;top: 26%;}
```

When you hover or click any of the image link, some info attached to that specific link becomes visible in a sidebar.

```
 <div id="map-hover-result" class="small-12 large-3 left">
  <ul>
   <li id="city1" class="hidden">some info here</li>  
   <li id="city2" class="hidden">some info here</li> 
   <li id="city3" class="hidden">some info here</li>  
   <li id="city4" class="hidden">some info here</li> 
   <li id="city5" class="hidden">some info here</li>
  </ul></div>
```

The way I handle the "hidden" class is like this. Is there any way I could optimize this?

```
 <script> $("a.city1").hover(function(){$('#city1').toggleClass('hidden');});
           $("a.city1").click(function(){$('#city1').toggleClass('hidden');});
          $("a.city2").hover(function(){$('#city2').toggleClass('hidden');});
           $("a.city2").click(function(){$('#city2').toggleClass('hidden');});
          $("a.city3").hover(function(){$('#city3').toggleClass('hidden');});
           $("a.city3").click(function(){$('#city3').toggleClass('hidden');});
          $("a.city4").hover(function(){$('#city4').toggleClass('hidden');});
           $("a.city4).click(function(){$('#city4').toggleClass('hidden');});
          $("a.city5").hover(function(){$('#city5').toggleClass('hidden');});
           $("a.city5").click(function(){$('#city5').toggleClass('hidden');});
 </script>
```

Comment: Where is `a.cityX` in your HTML ?

Comment: @l2aelba: I believe the `X` is intended to denote a numeral in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the mouseover, mouseout and click events within a single function

```
$("#map").find('a').on('mouseover mouseout click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cl = $(this).attr('class');
    $('#' + cl).toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5FYTY/1/)

Comment: is there way to modify the code so that when you click a new link, the old element gets the "hidden" class back? As it is now, you can click as many links as you want and all of them will become visible, instead of just the latest one. thanks

Comment: @user2997903 not as tidy but hopefully this will do what you are asking - http://jsfiddle.net/5FYTY/2/

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that (as your HTML shows) the `a` elements have only one class-name, and that class-name is equal to the `id` of the `li`:

```
$('a[class^="city"]').hover(function(){
    $('#' + this.className).toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9dHR7/1/).

References:

- [Attribute-starts-with (`[attribute^="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Answer (score 1):

Add a `data-*` attribute to the all links pointing to the right `city` and give them all a generic class

```
<a data-city="city1" class="city"><img class="large-12 small-8" src="fundita-mov.png"></a>
<a data-city="city2" class="city"><img class="large-12 small-8" src="fundita-mov.png"></a>
```

Then use 1 single selector for them all (you can also chain the 2 methods):

```
$("a.city").hover(function(){$('#' + $(this).data('city')).toggleClass('hidden');})
       .click(function(){$('#' + $(this).data('city')).toggleClass('hidden');});
```

You can even clean that up a bit more by using `.on`

```
$("a.city").on('hover click',function(){$('#' + (this).data('city')).toggleClass('hidden');});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your script to

```
$('#map').on('mouseenter mouseleave click', 'a[class^="city"]', function(){
   var classname = $(this).attr('class');
   $('#' + classname).toggleClass('hidden');
})
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/9dHR7/